# Why is this Javascript JSON String not valid?

Tags: javascript, json

This is the string in question:

```
var string = "{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\"someurl.com\">link</a>\"}";
```

When I un-escape the quotes (except the url) and [validate](http://jsonlint.com/), it appears to be valid:

```
{
    "CMD": "<a href=\"someurl.com\">link</a>"
}
```

But it breaks my Javascript program.

edit: Have also tried double escaping. The first double quote seems to get escaped, but not the second:

```
{
        "CMD": "<a href=\\"someurl.com\\">link</a>"
}
```

Offending code:

```
webSocket.send("{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\\\"link.com\\\">link</a>\"}");
```

Comment: Convert double quotes to single inside the string
{
    "CMD": "<a href=\'someurl.com\'>link</a>"
}

Comment: Wouldn't the \"someurl.com\" be unescaped as well? So you need to double escape them? Maybe?

Comment: try : `var string = "{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\\\"someurl.com\\\">link</a>\"}";`

Comment: Why is this an issue? You shouldn't be creating JSON strings by hand, you should use a library function for it, and it will almost surely get it right.

Comment: Simply use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use single `'` as below

```
{
    "CMD": "<a href='someurl.com'>link</a>"
}
```

`'` is equivalent to `"` for quoting HTML attribute values. This way JSONLint validates it.

These two HTMLs are equivalent/same.

```
<a href='someurl.com'>link</a>

<a href="someurl.com">link</a>
```

Comment: The question is about the string, not the object.

Comment: *"`'` is equivalent to `"` in javascript"* While true (well, *almost*), it's irrelevant in the above. The relevant thing to the above is that `'` [is valid for quoting HTML attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0).

Comment: This is the only thing that worked - double escaping and triple escaping double quotes didn't work.

Comment: @crm: This would also work: `"{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\\\"someurl.com\\\">link</a>\"}"` ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/11zs7zet/)), but the above is **much** simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute has additional `"`. You need to double escape it:

```
"{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\\\"someurl.com\\\">link</a>\"}"
```

Comment: This nor double escaping works in Javascript for me.

Comment: Well, post your code. `JSON.parse("{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\\\"someurl.com\\\">link</a>\"}");` works for me.

Comment: `webSocket.send("{\"CMD\":\"<a href=\\\"link.com\\\">link</a>\"}");`

Comment: What do you do with the string after that? `JSON.parse` on it will work, sending it should work as well, because it is simply a string.

Comment: It is sent to a Java server where it is parsed as a JSONObject: `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stringJson);`

Comment: Can you print the string from Java to see how it looks like?

Comment: This is the Java JSON parsed object using single quotes from Javascript:`{"CMD":"MESSAGE","BODY":"<a href='link.com'>link</a>","ROOM":"r","SESSIONID":"0","USERNAME":"ddd"}`

Answer (score 0):

Change like this :

```html
{ "CMD": "<a href=\"someurl.com\">link</a>" }
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive?